# SXA Checlikst filter not working with special characters

Tags: sxa, content-search

SXA Checlikst filter is not working when filtering by a choice with a special character like : '&' then filter by other filter

[image]

I think the problem is in the encoding because when I checked the Url the first choice was not right :

> Blockquote
>   https://my_instance_name//sxa/search/results/?l=en&s={57C05478-9434-4B19-BD13-F4C248DB8AF6}&itemid={E089DD6D-ECFB-4C8D-AF7E-A4CEF507D92F}&sig=SearchResults1&relatedaspectoflifesearchable=Business%20Library%20&templatedisplayname=Service%20Subtopic&e=0&q=&p=10&v={8D1038ED-B68C-4D02-B5D4-430F30288136}

If you notice in the Url there is only :
Business%20Library%20

If I write : Business%20Library%20%26%20Directory, It works successfullt

Comment: You should open a ticket with Sitecore Support. This is probably a bug in the javascript for the checkbox filter (there are a few in that one).

Comment: @Mohamed Mosa: Which version of SXA are you using? I've just tested your case quickly and I added such value: "Library & Directory" to my items. When I start filtering by it, it's what I've in the URL "myfield=library%20%26%20directory" and it's filtering correctly results.

Comment: I'm using SXA 1.7, it's working correctly I know, I'm talking in case there are two checklist filters, when I filter by the second filter after I filtered by the first, This case happens, it happens when appending other parameter to the URL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did a small investigation and it's actually a bug in front-end part of SXA search logic.

If this is a blocker for you then you could apply following changes to make Checklist Filter work:

- component-search-query.js - replace `item` with `encodeURIComponent(item)` in `updateHash()` function

  [image]
- component-search-results-filter.js - replace `facetValue = currentFacet.data('facetvalue')` with `facetValue = decodeURIComponent(currentFacet.data('facetvalue'))` in `updateFacet()` function:
  [image]

You will find both scripts under `/sitecore/media library/Base Themes/SearchTheme`.

**Important!** **This is not an official fix**, I've not tested it fully and with other search renderings (I can imagine some potential problems). Treat it as a workaround if this bug is blocking you.

Comment: It works Thank you so much, I also have a concern, in Arabic language the checklist filter is not working at all, there is a problem with the encoding (I think the encoding happens by escape() and the decoding happens by decodeURIComponent()), the URL was  :
relatedaspectoflifesearchable=%u062A%u0635%u0648%u064A%u062A

however after I applied the above fix for my problem, the Arabic checklist filter is not working also but with a different behavior, the URL now is :
relatedaspectoflifesearchable=undefined